# Datatable not showing value in last column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

In my project I using datatables for listing values from database. But in one datatable have an issue that it's not displaying last column of the data row, It show's the column header and the json has includes the value of that column.

The issue is in production

[image]

The datatable configuration code in javascript

```
  return {
    index: function () {
      varColumns = [
        { "visible": 0 }, /* ID column */
        { "sortable": false },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
      ];
      DataTable.init('#managed_table', varColumns, true, 'input#selected_items', '.item_lookup');
    }
  };
```

Datatable code in rails

```
class OrderItemsDatatable < GenericDatatable
private

  def data
    records.map do |order_item|
      [order_item.id,
       order_item.photo.select.url ? raw("<img src='/photos/item/select/#{order_item.code}' />") : "<img src='/assets/images/default/select_#{order_item.category}.jpg' />",
       order_item.vendor.name,
       order_item.inventory.location.region,
       order_item.code,
       order_item.name,
       integerize(order_item.width),
       integerize(order_item.height),
       order_item.lighting
      ]
    end
  end

----------
----------
----------

  def columns
    %w(items.id items.photo vendors.name locations.region items.code items.name, items.width, items.height, items.lighting)
  end
end
```

Its working in development.

[image]

Comment: Data missing in production?

Comment: If it is working in dev, your best asset would be to review the code across both environments yourself because it is difficult to judge from here.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - No. The production has the Lit column data.

Comment: You only have 8 entries in `varColumns`

Comment: sorry John that was my mistake. Actual code it have 9 entries in varColumns.